# Android: How can I take advantage of Android's ability to rotate/scale a canvas

Tags: android, graphics

I'm using a SurfaceView (actually I'm tweaking the Android sample app "LunarView"). I've changed the doDraw() method of that sample app so that I can draw my own things to the canvas provided in the call. This is working fine, I can draw my own things to the canvas and they're showing up in the emulator fine.

What I would like to do, if possible, is have the canvas adapt to the X and Y scale orientation my app naturally uses. For example, my app needs to draw a simple X-Y graph, but I need the X axis to be "down" the screen and the Y axis to be "to the right". (In other words, a typical graph but rotated 90 degrees clockwise.)

I thought that the Matrix class, with its setRectToRect(...) method would be just the ticket for this, but it isn't working for me. I've tried a whole bunch of different invocations of setRectToRect(...) and whenever I call it my canvas shows nothing. If I comment out the calls, my canvas shows what I expect.

The canvas class has some super-powerful methods for scaling and translating, so it just seems natural to me that it would also support the type of axis swap I need, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do it!

Any help would be great,
Thanks
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich,

You can use canvas functions....

You need to tell it where to rotate, using center coordinates usually work best. Find center of canvas and call this: canvas.rotate(90,cx,cy);

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. The origin was already where I wanted it, so my final solution was this:
`canvas.rotate(90);
canvas.setScale(1, -1);`